# Wifi after install SSD not working if bandwidth is 40mhz

Tags: networking, hard-drive, wireless-networking, ssd

It is strange but my all in one computer wifi was working with HDD. I decided to put a SSD instead (samsumg evo 860).

I install windows on it (ssd) and my wifi stopped working. I tried to install other drives, windows again... no success.

So I went to my wifi router (2.4 ghz) setup to see if I could change something. The bandwidth was automatic (and it was automatic since some years) so I set it to 20mhz and wifi start working again on my computer.

I know with 2.4 ghz we should use 20mhz, but all other devices was working in 40mhz for years including my all in one computer with HDD. Any ideas why after install my SSD the wifi has this interference in 40mgz?

Comment: Since a new drive meant re-installing Windows (which is what you did), Windows would have installed an up to date Wireless driver and this probably made the change to the 2.4 GHz setup used.

Comment: @John thanks for your answer. But my windows before (with HDD) had all recent updates the same version of drives I install in the SSD. I think it was not the problem. :/

Comment: Check your router setup. My Cisco Wireless router has only 20 MHz and 20/40 MHz frequencies for the 2.4 GHz band. So there is no pure 40 MHz setup and I think what you are seeing is quite normal.  You can try deleting your wireless profile entirely, restart and set it up again. See if that changes anything.